# Why are nested objects retrieved from a OpenFeign request to a Spring Data Rest endpoint null?

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas, hateoas

I have the following domain classes in my client app:

```
@Value
public class Car {

  private Long id;
  private Model model;

}

@Value
public class Make {
  
  private Long id;
  private String name;
  private Model model;
}

@Value
public class Model {
  
  private Long id;
  private String name;

}
```

My client app tries to get this data from a Spring Data Rest endpoint that return a HATEOAS response. The client does this via OpenFeign:

```
@FeignClient(name="car-service")
@Validated
public interface CarClient {

    @GetMapping("/api/cars")
    CollectionModel<Car> getAllCars();
}
```

But the each car has its `make=null`. How can I get make and model to be returned?

Comment: can you put a reproducer to github ?

Comment: you don't have a 'make' field in your 'Car'.